# Activerecord query to include count of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model User and it has many posts. To query first 5 users, I do:

```
User.all :limit => 5
```

which returns a user which is good, but when getting the count of # of posts each user has, it queries the DB again:

```
a_user.posts.count
```

Is there a way I can avoid this query and get the count with the first query ? I am looping through users and it blocks each time it query for user's post's count.

Comment: I believe that [Counter Cache Column](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has a built in method, that has to be set to true when declaring associations like has_many, and also, you must add a column to the database.

set `counter_cache: true` when you declare the `has_many` association

add `#{table_name}_count` to the database and it will be incremented and decremented automatically, so you can select this column directly when you query for the first five users.

More info on:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: This is better than my answer if all you need is count and you can change your schema

Comment: Set counter_cache: true at belongs_to, not has_many. has_many's counter_cache: option is for specifying non-standard counter column name.

Comment: does counter_cache take care of lost update problem?

Answer (score 2):

The method your looking for the the rails eager loading `#includes`, which will still create two queries (but not the 6 if you do `User.all, :limit=>5` and then `user.posts` on each), but will load the posts in one query:

```
User.includes(:posts).limit(5)
```

which should create the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
  WHERE (posts.user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)) # Numbers are found ID
```

You can find this information from [Active Record Query Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)