# Sorting comments by # of questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models: posts, comments and questions (note: questions belong to comments). I would like to sort each posts questions by the number of comments they each have. I have a comments partial that is called by my posts show page that shows all the comments.

Posts show:

```
<%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
```

Comments partial:

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
```

and the posts controller:

```
def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comments = Post.order("created_at desc")
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198401/activerecord-query-to-include-count-of-associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a counter inside the commments table to record how many questions it have.

the migration file

```
class AddQuestionsCountToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :commments, :questions_count, :integer, :default => 0
  end
end
```

the model files

```
class Comment
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Post show

```
<%= render :partial => @post.comments.order('comments.questions_count desc') %>
```

Comment: This gives me a SQLException 'no such column: comments.questions_count: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?'

Comment: @user2759575 you have to do a migration and add this column

Comment: sorry, new to rails. You add counter_cache => true in the question model but then what would the migration look like?